# Change private string from another class

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, properties, private

I'm wondering as to why my private variable 'name' within my Events class won't change when I access the property from my Leisure class which inherits from Events. I need Leisure to use the properties to change it, and then in my form class, it should be able to read the value of 'name' from events. See below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form //Main form class
{
    private string eventType; //used for event type selection
    private string formEventName; //used to store selected event name


     private void itemSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //encapsulation
        Events myEv = new Events();
        string name=itemInput.Text; 
        myEv.myEvent(eventType, name);
        formEventName = myEv.myName;
        txtOutput.Text = "Event name is " + formEventName + "\r\n";            
    }

class Events:Form1
{
    private string name; //private variable for event name      
     public string myName //used to change property value depending on what eveny type/ event name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }   
    }
    public void myEvent(string eventType, string eventName) //variable recieved from main form class
    {
        if (eventType == "Leisure")
        {

           Leisure myLes = new Leisure(); 
           myLes.eventNames(eventName);  

        }
        else
        {
            //test for other event types
        }  
    }

    class Leisure:Events
 {
    public void eventNames(string eventName) 
    {

        //when adding new items add one with a capital and one without
        myEventNames.Add("music");
        myEventNames.Add("Music");
        if (myEventNames.Contains(eventName))
        {
            myName = eventName;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("item not found, please try again"); //error message
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where comes `myEventNames` from?

Comment: myEventNames is a list within the class, sorry I must of forgot to copy that part of the code

Comment: Honestly, the design at a high level troubles me.  These forms almost certainly shouldn't be inheriting from each other.  You're confusing yourself because you think you're having access to the methods of all of the parents, but you're not actually interacting with your parents because those methods aren't being called on the proper instances.  Inheritance isn't the proper way for these forms to communicate.

Comment: Why are `Events` and `Leasure` types of forms?  From what I can see, they shouldn't be forms at all because they're not shown and aren't interacting with UI elements beyond a messagebox.  What's the true purpose of these two classes?  What are they, at a high level, trying to accomplish?

Comment: Events and Leisure are just classes. Events should be able to access information from the leisure class and then return this information into the form

Answer (score 2):

The `myName` property you are using changes the `name` private field of myLes instance and not the name private field of myEv instance created in the ItemSend_Click.

In an Object Oriented Language when you create an instance of a class, that instance has a copy of every non-static private/public variable declared in the class. So when you write

```
   Leisure myLes = new Leisure();
```

you are creating an instance of Leisure class, but this instance, while inherithing from Events has a different set of internal variables and not the same variables of the current Event instance (myEv).

Looking at your code I suggest to create a third class called

```
public class EventFactory
{
    public Event CreateEvent(string eventType, string eventName)
    {
        switch(enventType)
        {
            case "Leisure":
                 Leisure myLes = new Leisure(); 
                 myLes.eventNames(eventName);  
                 return myLes;
            // case Add other specialized events here:
            // break;
            default:
                 return null;
        }
    }
}
```

change your Events class removing the inheritance from Form1 (not needed as far as I can tell) and the method myEvent

now your ItemSend_Click could be written in this way

```
private void itemSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Events myEv = new EventFactory().CreateEvent(eventType, itemInput.Text);
    formEventName = myEv.myName;
    txtOutput.Text = "Event name is " + formEventName + "\r\n";            
}
```

this works because `Leisure` derives from `Events` and you could treat every Leisure instance as an Event instance.

Comment: In which case, how do I create an object of the Leisure class within the current Event instance. Is there a way to do it without using the 'new' operator?

Answer (score 2):

It seems wrong that `Events` inherits from `Form1`.

When you say `new Events()`, you get a new object, unrelated to the existing form, and any changes you make to it have no effect on the existing form.  That happens again when you say `new Leisure()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just change `myName` of the `myLes (Leisure)` variable in your `myEv` field, thats why myEv.myName is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem that you're having is just a small symptom of major fundamental problems in your code that will only continue to manifest themselves as you continue.

I've re-written what you have into something that's more in line with what is more traditionally seen for what you're trying to do.  It's not perfect, and I've tried to keep things fairly simple so as to not throw too much at you at once.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form //Main form class
{
    private TextBox itemInput;
    private TextBox txtOutput;
    private string eventType; //used for event type selection
    private string formEventName; //used to store selected event name

    private void itemSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = itemInput.Text;
        try
        {
            Event myEvent = Event.Create(eventType, name);
            txtOutput.Text = "Event name is " + myEvent.Name + "\r\n";
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)//if the event name isn't valid
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Event
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Event(string eventName)
    {
        Name = eventName;
    }
    public static Event Create(string eventType, string eventName)
    {
        if (eventType == "Leisure")
        {

            Leisure myLes = new Leisure(eventName);
            return myLes;

        }
        //  else if { ... } test for other event types
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class Leisure : Event
{
    private static List<string> myEventNames =
        new List<string>() { "music", "Music" };
    public Leisure(string eventName)
        : base(eventName)
    {
        if (!myEventNames.Contains(eventName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid Leisure event name");
        }
    }
}
```

So, let's go over some of the changes.  First off, `Event` doesn't inherit from `Form1`.  It should not do so.  An event is not conceptually a type of form at all, let alone that particular type of form.  An `Event` should have no knowledge of any form, in any way, not just inheritance.  It's just some other class that `Form1` will use, but it could just as easily be used by any other type of class, form or otherwise.

In addition to making `Event` not inherit from `Form`, I've made it abstract.  It doesn't have any abstract methods, it's just that you shouldn't ever be creating just an plain `Event`, you should only ever actually create some specific type of event.  Being a common base class, it's easiest to prevent accidental creation and to help improve readability by making it `abstract`.

I've also made `Event` immutable.  Rather than allowing name to be changed at any time, creating an event without giving it a name, and then changing it later, I have configured it such that you need to provide the name and type before creating the event, and then there's no way of changing it once it's created.  The `Name` is set in the constructor, and I have added a static `Create` method which is where the logic can go for choosing the proper subtype of `Event` and actually creating it.  This is a simple version of the "Factory Pattern".  Note that normally I wouldn't pass the type in as a string.  I would make it something like an `Enum`, so that it's easier to tell what the valid options are.

Now onto `Leisure`.  Logically, `Leisure` really is an `Event` and should inherit from it.  Your problems were steming from the fact that you created an instance of `Event`, and also an instance of `Leisure`, and assumed that they shared the same variables.  They don't, but that confusion should go away now that you can't ever have an instance of `Event`.

When a `Leisure` is created it uses the base class constructor to set `Name`, since it doesn't have access to set the property itself.

From what I can see `myEventNames` is just a list of valid names, and it doesn't appear to change between different types of `Leisure` instances, so it makes sense for it to be `static`, which means it's shared between all instances and is only created once.

I also moved the `MessageBox` call out of the `Leisure` type's constructor.  Instead I'm throwing an exception.  The main idea here is that you shouldn't mix your UI code with your business code.  `Event` and `Leisure` are both business objects and shouldn't know anything about what, if any, UI exists.  You should be able to use them from a console app, an ASP application, etc.  On top of that, since what we're trying to say is that this is an invalid name and the type shouldn't exist, the end result of throwing an Excpetion in the constructor is that the object never becomes "valid".  We don't allow the creation of an object that shouldn't exist, as opposed to allowing them to continue using the object anyway.

That exception is caught with the `try/catch` block in `Form1`, where it shows the appropriate `MessageBox` based on the failure to create the event.